# How to dynamic load a node_module package on a VueCLI 3 web application

Tags: webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm working with VueCLI project, in this project there is a specific payment page which needs to a certain encryption. I'm using 'jsencrypt' npm package.

I Would like to load this package ONLY when the user is in the page, not for ever user that enters into the webapp.

I alread tried fallowing [this](https://vuedose.tips/tips/dynamic-imports-in-vue-js-for-better-performance/) tutorial which tells me to import the module like:

```
const jsencrypt = () => import('jsencrypt');
```

instead of

```
import jsencrypt from 'jsencrypt';
```

Fallowing this tutorial, I noticed that a new chunk was added on webpack bundle results

[image]

However I was not able to use the 'jsencrypt', When I use it, I got the fallowing error:

> TypeError: i.setPublicKey is not a function

And the new chunk was not load on my application, just the previous two:

[image]

What am I missing in order to load this module dynamically?

Comment: You might want to take a look at you webpack config and search for optimization.splitChunks which is the section for the SplitChunksPlugin.

That's the plugin which enables webpack to split packages loaded from node_modules.

Check this out:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

The tutorial you linked to covers only dynamic loading of vue components.

Comment: I dont have one, I'm using VueCLI as mentioned above. Using vue-cli , we have a vue.config.js file

Comment: vue.config.js is simply the name of your webpack config. That's where you need to check for optimization.splitChungks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about how you are trying to call the module, and the dyncamic declaration is correct !

I got such error when declare and call it like this :

```
const jsencrypt = () => import('jsencrypt')

jsencrypt.doSomeThing()
```

but the correct way is to declare and call in this way :

```
const getJsencrypt = () => import('jsencrypt')

getJsencrypt().then((jsencrypt) => jsencrypt.doSomeThing())
```